# Select one of multiple columns into a new column Ask Question

Tags: postgresql, select

My database table looks like table 1 below:

```
Table 1:
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |   id     | distance | duration_sec | speed | foot | bike | car | bus | metro     |
    | -----------+----------+--------------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+---------|
    | 461275000 |  2661.08 |          953 |  2.79 | f    | f    | f   | t   | f        |
    | 451918000 |  6289.75 |         1381 |  4.55 | f    | f    | t   | f   | f        |
    | 453044000 |  5938.43 |          950 |  6.25 | t    | f    | t   | f   | f        |
    | 445673000 |  2734.22 |         2333 |  1.17 | t    | f    | f   | f   | f        |
    | 456831000 |  7566.85 |         2071 |  3.65 | t    | f    | f   | t   | f        |
    | 443467000 |  1763.64 |          991 |  1.78 | t    | f    | t   | f   | f        |
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to select into a new column `mode`, the column for which one of (`foot, bike, car, bus, metro`) is `TRUE`. For rows where `foot` and another mode are `TRUE`, I have to make a decision considering the `speed`. If the `speed` is above 2m/s, I consider it as another mode, else as `foot`.

The end result should be as in table 2 (decision preceded with `#` sign). How do I do this?

```
Table 2:
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |    id     | distance | duration_sec | speed | foot | bike | car | bus | metro | mode      |
    +------------+----------+--------------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+-------+--------- |
    | 461275000 |  2661.08 |          953 |  2.79 | f    | f    | f   | t   | f     |  bus      |
    | 451918000 |  6289.75 |         1381 |  4.55 | f    | f    | t   | f   | f     |  car      |
    | 453044000 |  5938.43 |          950 |  6.25 | t    | f    | t   | f   | f     |  #car     |
    | 445673000 |  2734.22 |         2333 |  1.17 | t    | f    | f   | f   | f     |  foot     |
    | 456831000 |  7566.85 |         2071 |  3.65 | t    | f    | f   | t   | f     |  #bus     |
    | 443467000 |  1763.64 |          991 |  1.78 | t    | f    | t   | f   | f     |  #foot    |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need a way to decide `mode` is `foot` only when the entire trip is by `foot`, (not `foot-> bus`, `foot -> car` etc)

**EDIT**

Just to add details to my question. the columns `foot, bike car bus` and `metro` show travel mode used. Some trips used more than one mode e.g `foot -> car`. My goal is to select a single travel mode per row. I can, for instance, consider the `distance` travelled, if it's above a threshold (say 4km), this is typically done by non-foot mode, so I consider it as `car` mode as whole.

For cases when two other modes are true (say `bus` and `metro`), I want to completely ignore that row.

Foot mode should only be considered as `foot` when only `foot` is `TRUE` or very low `speed` for short `distance` below 2km

Comment: What is the priority? for example, if car and bus are true, what value must be set? the same when foot and 2 or more additional values are true and speed is above 2 m/s. In general - 1 long CASE WHEN or 2 nested.

Comment: For cases where for instance  `car` and `bus` or `bus` and `metro`  are true, I want to ignore the entire row as there are not many such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You want nested CASE statements.  You haven't full described the problem, we can't give you a full answer.  One branch would list 'foot' as the first priority, and other as the last priority (or maybe not consider it at all, or consider it an error) Something like:

```
CASE WHEN speed > 2 then
  CASE WHEN bike then 'bike'
  CASE WHEN car then 'car'
  ...
  CASE when foot then 'foot and/or error'
  ELSE 'none'
  END
ELSE
  CASE when foot then 'foot'
  CASE WHEN bike then 'bike'
  CASE WHEN car then 'car'
  ...
  ELSE 'none'
  END
END
```

You can't ignore a row from the select-list, so you probably need to write logic in two places.  In the WHERE clause, to ignore rows with a true in more than one non-foot column, plus a CASE expression like the above in the select list, (or in the SET list if doing an UPDATE).

Comment: I edit my question to give some details.